# How to open ports in Cisco ASA 5505 using ASDM?

Tags: firewall, cisco, hardware, cisco-asa, port

am new to cisco and i badly need help in opening ports using ASDM.

I already tried natting but it only allows 1 outside and 1 inside rule

ex. Inside Static Rules 10.x.x.x outside 72.x.x.x Outside Static Rules 72.x.x.x outside 10.x.x.x

i can access common ports like 80,21,23,25 and etc.

what i need is to open ports

1000-1100

i can't seem to do it right. I also tried access list but still now working. I am not sure if i did it right though.

If someone knows something about this i would appreciate it if you could answer my question with instructions on how to open ports.

Thanks

Comment: I am using ASDM 6.1 ... just in case you need that info

Comment: Can you clarify how your firewall is set up now?  Have you NAT'd the outside address to the inside address, or are you looking to NAT the ports to different inside addresses on the same public address?  What does your ACL on the outside interface have configured?

Comment: Firewall has default factory settings. It has two NAT rules. 1 inside (10.x.x.x outside 72.x.x.x) and 1 Outside (72.x.x.x outside 10.x.x.x)

Comment: Are those addresses for the specific host address?  Is the 10.x.x.x address one for the internal system that this connection should be getting sent to?

Comment: yes ... 10.x.x.x is the internal ip address of my server while 72.x.x.x is the public i of my server ... that is the ip that will be used to connect to my server. I have an application which needs to use port 1000 that is why i need to know how to open ports.

Comment: Ok - what's your outside interface ACL configured with?